# Cannot print on HP Color Laser 150a

Tags: 20.04, usb, printing, hp

I have just purchased a HP Color Laser 150a printer and connected it through the USB port. However, nothing happens when I try to print.

I could add the printer on CUPS but when I tried HPLIP it did not recognise the printer (checking on the HPLIP webpage, it seems it may not be a supported device)

> lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04ca:7053 Lite-On Technology Corp. HP HD Camera

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader

Bus 001 Device 040: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.

Bus 001 Device 048: ID 03f0:ea2a HP, Inc HP Color Laser 150a

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

> lpinfo -v

network ipp

file cups-brf:/

network beh

direct usb://HP/Color%20Laser%20150?serial=CNB2M6JKX4

network socket

network lpd

network ipps

network http

network https

direct hp

direct hpfax

I am no expert, but this seems to indicate that the printer is being recognised. So where's the breakdown?

Comment: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-color-laser-150-printer-series/24494352/model/24494353/swItemId/ly-227001-2

Comment: Thank you. I added this driver, but still no luck. When I print a Test Page - it registers the job and the light on the printer flashes but nothing happens. The print Job is listed as "Stopped"

Answer (score 0):

That printer is  really a rebadged Samsung printer (HP bought the Samsung printer division). You can use the Samsung CLP-315 driver that is integrated into CUPS and works fine as is almost the same printer with another case (works fine printing both color and BW).